# How to implement multiple delegates in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

In Objective-C, delegates such as UITableViewControllerDelegate are protocols, so I can implement multiple in one class.

In Monotouch, all the iOS delegates are exposed as C# classes. This makes it impossible to implement two delegate on a single controller class, since C# (rightly, IMO) only allows single inheritance.

Does the delegate declarations exist as C# interfaces somewhere in the Monotouch framework ? (This would be the closest we could come to the protocol from Objective-C)

What are my options if I need to implement multiple delegates on a class in Monotouch / C# ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `WeakDelegate` to do this, but you have to have all the `Export` decorations correct. Documentation on weak delegates near the bottom [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events). [Here](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XPlatUtils/blob/develop/XPlatUtils.iOS.Samples/Controllers/HomeController.cs) is an example of `UITableViewSource` with weak delegates.

I'm not sure exactly why Xamarin had to use classes instead of interfaces for Obj-C protocols, but I'm guessing it is a limitation they had to workaround.

Comment: The reason classes are used instead of interfaces is that Obj-C protocols can have optional methods. Managed interfaces can't.

Comment: That makes sense... It would be nice if there were a set of public string constants for all the selectors used in MonoTouch to help with this--those strings are all in there already, just not exposed.

Comment: No, I was thinking compile-time constants in monotouch.dll would be a great feature for Xamarin to add. Something like `UITableView.Selectors.GetCell`, for example.